# Chunk a JSON Array of Objects until each Array item is of byte length < a Static Threshold

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a `list` of `dict` that follow a consistent structure where each `dict` has a `list` of integers. However, I need to make sure each `dict` has a bytesize (when converted to a JSON string) less than a specified threshold.

If the `dict` exceeds that bytesize threshold, I need to chunk that dict's integer `list`.

Attempt:

```
import json

payload: list[dict] = [
    {"data1": [1,2,3,4]},
    {"data2": [8,9,10]},
    {"data3": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}
]

# Max size in bytes we can allow. This is static and a hard limit that is not variable.
MAX_SIZE: int = 25

def check_and_chunk(arr: list):

    def check_size_bytes(item):
        return True if len(json.dumps(item).encode("utf-8")) > MAX_SIZE else False

    def chunk(item, num_chunks: int=2):
        for i in range(0, len(item), num_chunks):
            yield item[i:i+num_chunks]

    # First check if the entire payload is smaller than the MAX_SIZE
    if not check_size_bytes(arr):
        return arr

    # Lets find the items that are small and items that are too big, respectively
    small, big = [], []

    # Find the indices in the payload that are too big
    big_idx: list = [i for i, j in enumerate(list(map(check_size_bytes, arr))) if j]

    # Append these items respectively to their proper lists
    item_append = (small.append, big.append)
    for i, item in enumerate(arr):
        item_append[i in set(big_idx)](item)
    
    # Modify the big items until they are small enough to be moved to the small_items list
    for i in big:
        print(i)
    # This is where I am unsure of how best to proceed. I'd like to essentially split the big dictionaries in the 'big' list such that it is small enough where each element is in the  'small' result.
```

Example of a possible desired result:

```
payload: list[dict] = [
    {"data1": [1,2,3,4]},
    {"data2": [8,9,10]},
    {"data3": [1,2,3,4]},
    {"data3": [5,6,7]}
]
```

Comment: When you split, does it matter how big the individual chunks are?

Comment: @Nick not really, as long as I can get the big items down to below the MAX_SIZE threshold, the chunks can be arbitrary amounts. I initially thought just halving them recursively might be the best path but not sure.

Comment: Halving them recursively is definitely a reasonable approach and quite possibly the fastest (if less efficient space-wise) to do it.

Comment: @Nick I guess my method of thought would be: Halve them recursively and the base case would be when each "chunk" is < ```max_size```.

Comment: Yeah, I think that would be easy compared to computing lengths of chunks of the list to try and get the optimal fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, a simple approach to this task is to recursively split the input list until the output dict meets the size requirement. This will give more evenly sized lists in the output, but may result in more dicts than are absolutely necessary (and would be produced by one of the length accumulation approaches).

```
import json

def split_list_dict(dl, limit):
    def split_dict_list(dd, limit):
        def json_len(ll):
            return sum(map(len, map(str, ll))) + 2 * len(ll)    # 2 * len(ll) allows for [] and , 
        
        ll = next(iter(dd.values()))
        key = next(iter(dd.keys()))
        dict_jsonlen = len(json.dumps(dd))
        if dict_jsonlen <= limit:
            yield dd
            return
        list_jsonlen = json_len(ll)
        keylen = dict_jsonlen - list_jsonlen
        split_point = len(ll) // 2
        yield from split_dict_list({ key : ll[:split_point] }, limit)
        yield from split_dict_list({ key : ll[split_point:] }, limit)
    
    for dd in dl:
        yield from split_dict_list(dd, limit)

MAX_SIZE: int = 25

payload: list[dict] = [
    {"data1": [1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {"long_data_name": [1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {"data3": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]},
    {"data4": [100, 200, -1, -10, 200, 300, 12, 13]},
]

print(list(split_list_dict(payload, MAX_SIZE)))
```

Output:

```
[
  {'data1': [1, 2, 3, 4]},
  {'long_data_name': [1]},
  {'long_data_name': [2]},
  {'long_data_name': [3]},
  {'long_data_name': [4]},
  {'data3': [1, 2, 3]},
  {'data3': [4, 5, 6]},
  {'data3': [7, 8, 9]},
  {'data3': [10, 11, 12]},
  {'data4': [100, 200]},
  {'data4': [-1, -10]},
  {'data4': [200, 300]},
  {'data4': [12, 13]}
]
```

Answer (score 3):

My approach starts with the list of integers. I will take one out of the existing list (which I call `input_sequence`) and place into a new list (`output_sequence`) until I go over the length limit. At which point, I will back up one number and build the "chunk".

```py
import json
import logging
import pprint
from collections import deque

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

MAX_SIZE: int = 25


def split(key, input_sequence, limit, out):
    """Split the `input_sequence` into several smaller ones.

    The result will be appended to the `out` list.    
    """
    input_sequence = deque(input_sequence)
    output_sequence = []
    
    while input_sequence:
        # Move an element from input_sequence to output_sequence
        element = input_sequence.popleft()
        output_sequence.append(element)

        # Build the dictionary in bytes
        dict_str = json.dumps({key: output_sequence})
        dict_binary = dict_str.encode("utf-8")
        actual_length = len(dict_binary)
        logging.debug("dict_binary=%r, len=%r", dict_binary, actual_length)

        # If the length is over the limit, then back off one element
        # And produce the result
        if actual_length > limit:
            logging.debug("Over the limit")
            output_sequence.pop()
            input_sequence.appendleft(element)
            out.append({key: output_sequence})
            output_sequence = []

    # Left over
    if output_sequence:
        out.append({key: output_sequence})


def check_and_chunk(arr: list, limit):
    out = []
    for dict_object in arr:
        for key, seq in dict_object.items():
            split(key, seq, limit, out)
    return out


payload: list[dict] = [
    {"data1": [1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {"data2": [8, 9, 10]},
    {"data3": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]},
    {"data4": list(range(20))},
]

pprint.pprint(check_and_chunk(payload, MAX_SIZE))
```

Here is the output.

```
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data1": [1]}', len=14
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data1": [1, 2]}', len=17
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data1": [1, 2, 3]}', len=20
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data1": [1, 2, 3, 4]}', len=23
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data2": [8]}', len=14
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data2": [8, 9]}', len=17
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data2": [8, 9, 10]}', len=21
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data3": [1]}', len=14
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data3": [1, 2]}', len=17
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data3": [1, 2, 3]}', len=20
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data3": [1, 2, 3, 4]}', len=23
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data3": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}', len=26
DEBUG:root:Over the limit
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data3": [5]}', len=14
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data3": [5, 6]}', len=17
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data3": [5, 6, 7]}', len=20
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [0]}', len=14
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [0, 1]}', len=17
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [0, 1, 2]}', len=20
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [0, 1, 2, 3]}', len=23
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]}', len=26
DEBUG:root:Over the limit
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [4]}', len=14
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [4, 5]}', len=17
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [4, 5, 6]}', len=20
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [4, 5, 6, 7]}', len=23
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}', len=26
DEBUG:root:Over the limit
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [8]}', len=14
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [8, 9]}', len=17
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [8, 9, 10]}', len=21
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [8, 9, 10, 11]}', len=25
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]}', len=29
DEBUG:root:Over the limit
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [12]}', len=15
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [12, 13]}', len=19
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [12, 13, 14]}', len=23
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [12, 13, 14, 15]}', len=27
DEBUG:root:Over the limit
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [15]}', len=15
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [15, 16]}', len=19
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [15, 16, 17]}', len=23
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [15, 16, 17, 18]}', len=27
DEBUG:root:Over the limit
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [18]}', len=15
DEBUG:root:dict_binary=b'{"data4": [18, 19]}', len=19
[{'data1': [1, 2, 3, 4]},
 {'data2': [8, 9, 10]},
 {'data3': [1, 2, 3, 4]},
 {'data3': [5, 6, 7]},
 {'data4': [0, 1, 2, 3]},
 {'data4': [4, 5, 6, 7]},
 {'data4': [8, 9, 10, 11]},
 {'data4': [12, 13, 14]},
 {'data4': [15, 16, 17]},
 {'data4': [18, 19]}]
```

#### Notes

- I use the logging library for debug output. If you want to turn off debugging, replace `logging.DEBUG` with `logging.WARN`
- I modified the signature of `check_and_chunk` to add the size limit and not relying on the global var
- I use the `deque` data structure, which behaves like a list, but with faster insert/remove from the left.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution based on counting lengths of elements and splitting the list based on that. Basically the code figures out the length of the `key` part of the JSON dict (`keylen`), then the length of each of the individual components of the list (`lens`), adding 2 to each length to account for `[]` for the first element and `,`  for each subsequent element. `bisect_right` is used to quickly determine where the split point needs to be to fit with the maximum length (`= MAX_SIZE - keylen`). The function is written as a generator to minimise memory usage for large datasets.

```py
import json
from bisect import bisect_right

def chunk_list_dict(dl, limit):
    def chunk_dict_list(dd, limit):
        ll = next(iter(dd.values()))
        key = next(iter(dd.keys()))
        keylen = len(json.dumps(dd)) - len(json.dumps(ll))
        llen = 0
        lens = [(llen := llen + len(str(i)) + 2) for i in ll]
        max_len = limit - keylen
        start = 0
        end = len(lens)
        out = []
        while start < end:
            last = bisect_right(lens, max_len)
            yield { key : ll[start:last] }
            max_len = lens[last-1] + limit - keylen
            start = last
        return out
    for d in dl:
        yield from chunk_dict_list(d, limit)

MAX_SIZE: int = 25

payload: list[dict] = [
    {"data1": [1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {"long_data_name": [1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {"data3": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]},
    {"data4": [100, 200, -1, -10, 200, 300, 12, 13]},
]

print(list(chunk_list_dict(payload, MAX_SIZE)))
```

Output:

```
[
  {'data1': [1, 2, 3, 4]},
  {'long_data_name': [1]},
  {'long_data_name': [2]},
  {'long_data_name': [3]},
  {'long_data_name': [4]},
  {'data3': [1, 2, 3, 4]},
  {'data3': [5, 6, 7, 8]},
  {'data3': [9, 10, 11]},
  {'data3': [12]},
  {'data4': [100, 200, -1]},
  {'data4': [-10, 200]},
  {'data4': [300, 12, 13]}
]
```

Comment: parameter `limit` is not used in `chunk_dict_list`. Otherwise, code works. +1

Comment: @HaiVu thanks for pointing that out. I got interrupted when I was converting my code into a function and missed changing the `MAX_SIZE` to `limit`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can use generator to yield the chunks of right size:

```py
import json

payload = [
    {"data1": [1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {"data2": [8, 9, 10]},
    {"data3": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]},
    {"data4": [100, 200, -1, -10, 200, 300, 12, 13]},
]

MAX_SIZE = 25


def get_chunks(lst):
    if len(lst) < 2:
        return lst

    curr, curr_len = [], 0
    for v in lst:
        s = str(v)
        # current length of all numbers + length of current number + number of `, ` + `[]`
        if curr_len + len(s) + 2 * len(curr) + 2 > MAX_SIZE:
            yield curr
            curr = [v]
            curr_len = len(s)
        else:
            curr.append(v)
            curr_len += len(s)

    if curr:
        yield curr


for d in payload:
    for k, v in d.items():
        for chunk in get_chunks(v):
            d = {k: chunk}
            print(f"{str(d):<40} {len(json.dumps(chunk).encode())=:<30}")
```

Prints:

```
{'data1': [1, 2, 3, 4]}                  len(json.dumps(chunk).encode())=12                            
{'data2': [8, 9, 10]}                    len(json.dumps(chunk).encode())=10                            
{'data3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}      len(json.dumps(chunk).encode())=24                            
{'data3': [9, 10, 11, 12]}               len(json.dumps(chunk).encode())=15                            
{'data4': [100, 200, -1, -10, 200]}      len(json.dumps(chunk).encode())=24                            
{'data4': [300, 12, 13]}                 len(json.dumps(chunk).encode())=13
```

Comment: This is really interesting. Thank you.

Comment: The only thing that I think has to be considered is the additional bytes from the payload key and object braces + colon, as those would be included in the total byte cost```{"data1": }```

Comment: @Coldchain9 You can then add additional param to `get_chunks(lst, length_of_key)` where `length_of_key` is `len('{"data1": }')` - and then include this in the total length computation

Comment: Within your ```for k, v in d.items():``` I added ```len(k)``` + 5, where 5 is the total cost of ```{```, ```}```, ```"```, ```"``` and ```:```. Should work every time assuming consistent payloads.

Comment: @Coldchain9 I'd use `len(f'{{"{k}": }}'.encode())` (note the space after `:`). Also it should handle any diacritics you have in key name. If diacritics are not a problem, then `len(k) + 6` is ok :)

Comment: good stuff :) thank you!